# iperf udp sequence number wireshark

Tags: packet-capture, packetloss, iperf, packet-analyzer

I'm using iperf for generating udp traffic and my objective is to measure paquet loss. I wanted to know if the first 4 Bytes of Iperf Data are currently the sequence number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I just implemented a check for this myself and I can confirm that the first 4 bytes of the data is in fact the sequence number.

Answer (score 0):

iperf & iperf2 have a standard dissector in Wireshark.
in iperf3, the sequence of fields has changed.
You can find an iperf3 dissector here: https://github.com/geertn444/iperf3_dissector